# require('fs') not working with browserify

Tags: browserify, fs

The following code generates error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
 var fs = require('fs');

 fs.readFileSync(filename);
```

Comment: Btw: You are using it wrong: readFileSync returns the file content and does not take a callback.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the brfs transform for this to work: https://github.com/substack/brfs

It will inline the file content into your script.

Comment: This only works if you have a string for the file name, like fs.readFileSync('abc.txt')

Comment: Ah, I see. You cannot use brfs with a variable, because it runs at compile time. The variable value is only known at runtime. It's impossible for brfs to inline the file if it does not know which one :-)